# React Native Maps : moving myLocationButton

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

Is there a way to move the position of MyLocationButton?
I am using Mapview with some additional views on top of it. one of those views is on top of the MyLocationButton, and aesthetically I would like to keep it like that --> so I should move the MyLocationButton instead. Is there a way to do it? x

```
<MapView
        style={styles.map}
        showsMyLocationButton = {true}
        showsUserLocation = {true}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: this.state.mylocation.coords.latitude,
          longitude: this.state.mylocation.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,//Zoom
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,//Zoom
        }}>
```

Comment: Make an custom location button with position absolute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it helps somebody, I found the solution to move the position of the button while the map continues to cover all the screen:

```
<MapView
(...)
        mapPadding={{top:0, right:0, left:0, bottom:230}}>
(...)
</Mapview>
```